# Webcam doesn't work in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: webcam

I have problems with my webcam. In Xubuntu 13.04 it's works perfectly, but when I upgraded to version 14.04 webcam doesn't work.

Comment: tells me it "can not locate package linux-headers-uname -r " I entered in : sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-'uname -r'

Answer (score 0):

Install the packages which contain common Webcam drivers.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```